# Why cant i send data using mongoose with node.js

Tags: node.js

Hello i have a problem,

## The below script works

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/mongo');

mongoose.model('users', {name: String});

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('users').find(function(err, users) {
    res.send(users);
  });
});
```

## but this code does not, why?

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/email');

mongoose.model('data', {name: String});

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('data').find(function(err, data) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});
```

I have a database for both, and only the first one returns content, the second one return an empty "[]".

I have a routes folder that contains index.js, and users.js, but it doesn't have data.js. Could this be the problem the problem?

Comment: Have you tried checking the database if it has data? Use something like RoboMongo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was,

Mongoose pluralizes collections.

That means that my mongodb database has a collection called "data"

and mongoose is searching for "datas"

Which means it wont find anything, and return empty data.